# How to click an object with Panel.ZIndex low than another in wpf?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, c#-4.0

In wpf, i have to click on an image with Panel.ZIndex="1", but this image is "under" another image with a Panel.ZIndex="2". The event MouseDown fail. How to do that?

Thanks in advance,
M.

```
<Grid >
    <Image Name="Image_1" 
           Panel.ZIndex="1" />

    <Image Name="Image_2" 
           Panel.ZIndex="2" />

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using [IsHitTestVisible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.ishittestvisible.aspx)

```
<Grid >
   <Image Name="Image_1" 
          Panel.ZIndex="1" />

    <Image Name="Image_2" IsHitTestVisible="false" 
          Panel.ZIndex="2" />
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a transparent image on top of all others, and have the click-event on that.

Answer (score 0):

The only way is to handle click on the `Image_2` and programmatically click on `Image_1`. You can't break the layout.

Or, of cource, change `ZIndex` property.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why isn't mouse event working? WPF has tunneling model for events, so you must have the ability to catch a mouse event on any element if another doesn't block it using e.Handled = true...